# Asp.Net MVC Html Helper Extension

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-2

What is the best way to extend Html Helper TextboxFor? Is there a way to reuse the defautl implementation?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can create your extension methods (in a static class), for example:

```
public static MvcHtmlString MyTextBoxFor<TModel, TProperty>(this HtmlHelper<TModel> helper, Expression<Func<TModel, TProperty>> expression)
        {
            // call original method
            MvcHtmlString result = InputExtensions.TextBoxFor(helper, expression);
            // do modification to result
            return result;
        }
```